# About Google Cloud dlpJob naming: is an 'i-' prefix added to a dlpJob's jobId by default?

Tags: google-cloud-dlp

I'm using Google Cloud DLP api to create dlpJob and get its status, and have question about the jobId of a dlpJob.

I find that when I create a dlpJob with the jobId 'testJob', it will have the jobId 'i-testJob' assigned by Google Cloud, and I have to use 'i-testJob' for get/cancel/delete this dlpJob, instead of the other one.

I wonder is this 'i-' prefix always added to the user-defined jobId by default? Or are there cases when 'i-' will not be added or other prefix is added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are added by default. The prefix will change based on the type of the job. When creating jobs the complete resource name is returned to you, so it is best to use that instead of guessing the prefix.